# Error during batchUpdate of Google Spreadsheets API

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

following https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#example

```
  sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  auth: authClient,
  spreadsheetId: contents.spreadsheetId,
  resource: {
    requests: [
      {
        'insertDimension': {
          'range': {
            'dimension': 'ROWS',
            'endIndex': 2,
            'startIndex': 1,
            'sheetId': 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}...
```

Gives me **Error: Must specify at least one request.**

Comment: The error [`badRequest: Must specify at least one request.`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request) means that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid. This error can be thrown when trying to add a duplicate parent to a Drive item. It can also be thrown when trying to add a parent that would create a cycle in the directory graph. You may also check the recommendations in this [page](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request).

Comment: hello @abielita, thanks for your reply. reading in [this page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) in the Node.js tab, it seems like i am filling every required field for this request. what am i missing?

Comment: I think that your request body is correct. So can you show us your whole script? It might find the reason from it.

Comment: @Tanaike I have given up on using the googleapis library for Node and just queried the endpoints directly using a custom HTTP library instead. Simple and reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. When your problem was solved, if you show the solution, it may be helpful for users who have the same situation.